# How to directly post data from an app to a web page?

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to implement this card.io app to scan credit cards.

```
https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source
```

So in the app, once you scan the card there is a Send button that let you send the card number to where you want to send it.

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I want to send this card number directly to a web page, and the card number will appear on the card number field automatically.
https://cdt-co.000webhostapp.com/customer/checkout_guest/ellington_checkout.php

Can this be done? And if yes how?

Hope you could help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could send it as a GET parameter as

https://cdt-co.000webhostapp.com/customer/checkout_guest/ellington_checkout.php?cardno=asdf1234

Or a POST parameter when the link is clicked 
Or add it as a header to the request

Easiest approach would be to send it as a GET parameter.

**EDIT**

Just to clarify. Your sendMessage function would look like this:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    String url="https://cdt-co.000webhostapp.com/customer/checkout_guest/ellington_checkout.php?cardno="+message;
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData( Uri.parse(url));
    activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that mean that I need to save the data in a db first before I can get it and show in the web page? I need something that will directly post the data to the webpage without saving it in db.

Comment: No, if you use GET method,  you could get the parameter in PHP as $_GET["cardno"] in the web page. Then you can populate the value as needed

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to android dev, I'm actually reading up about volley to pass data from app to web. Do I still need to use volley or this will work as is?

Comment: That's alright. If you want to open webpage on a browser after user clicks on the button then it will work as is.
If you want the user to stay on the app after the click then you need to use a library like volley. 
please try the above code and check if it is what you wanted.

Comment: Hi, sorry just additional question. This approach where it redirects directly to my website, this is not a webview correct? Just opening a browser from the phone?

Comment: Yes, it is not WebView. To use a webview, you have to add a element called WebView in android layout file. A WebView is used to load web pages inside the android app. 
you can refer to this for details on WebViews: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm